# Custom Shape using layerlist in XML Android

Tags: android, android-layout

How can I create below custom drawable shapes using layer-list in XML.

[image: cut edged rectangle facing right]

[image: cut edged rectangle facing left]

Answer (score 1):

After couple of hours trying finally I am able to create this custom shape using `layer-list`.

**1. /res/drawable/custom_shape_one.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <!-- Rectangle -->
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <size
                android:width="300dp"
                android:height="80dp" />
            <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item
        android:right="80dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <size
                android:width="300dp"
                android:height="60dp" />
            <solid android:color="#F8F7F7" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item
        android:left="135dp">
        <rotate android:fromDegrees="67">
            <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <solid android:color="#F8F7F7" />
            </shape>
        </rotate>
    </item>

    <!-- Top Border -->
    <item
        android:right="61dp"
        android:bottom="78.8dp">
        <shape android:shape="line">
            <stroke
                android:color="#999999"
                android:width="1dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <!-- Right-Diagonal Border -->
    <item
        android:left="220dp">
        <rotate android:fromDegrees="67">
            <shape android:shape="line">
                <stroke
                    android:color="#999999"
                    android:width="1dp" />
            </shape>
        </rotate>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

**USE:**

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/custom_shape_one"/>
```

**OUTPUT:**

[image]

**2. /res/drawable/custom_shape_two.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <!-- Rectangle -->
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <size
                android:width="300dp"
                android:height="80dp" />
            <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item
        android:left="80dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <size
                android:width="300dp"
                android:height="60dp" />
            <solid android:color="#F8F7F7" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item
        android:right="135dp">
        <rotate android:fromDegrees="293">
            <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <solid android:color="#F8F7F7" />
            </shape>
        </rotate>
    </item>

    <!-- Top Border -->
    <item
        android:left="61dp"
        android:bottom="78.8dp">
        <shape android:shape="line">
            <stroke
                android:color="#999999"
                android:width="1dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <!-- Left-Diagonal Border -->
    <item
        android:right="220dp">
        <rotate android:fromDegrees="293">
            <shape android:shape="line">
                <stroke
                    android:color="#999999"
                    android:width="1dp" />
            </shape>
        </rotate>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

**USE:**

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/custom_shape_two"/>
```

**OUTPUT:**

[image]

**3. /res/drawable/custom_shape.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <size
                android:width="300dp"
                android:height="60dp" />
            <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item
        android:right="90dp">
        <rotate android:fromDegrees="67">
            <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <solid android:color="#F8F7F7" />
            </shape>
        </rotate>
    </item>
    <item
        android:left="90dp">
        <rotate android:fromDegrees="293">
            <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <solid android:color="#F8F7F7" />
            </shape>
        </rotate>
    </item>

    <item
        android:right="200dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <size
                android:width="300dp"
                android:height="60dp" />
            <solid android:color="#F8F7F7" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item
        android:left="200dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <size
                android:width="300dp"
                android:height="60dp" />
            <solid android:color="#F8F7F7" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <!-- Top-Right Line -->
    <item
        android:right="180dp"
        android:bottom="58.5dp">
        <shape android:shape="line">
            <stroke
                android:color="#999999"
                android:width="1dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <!-- Top-Right Line -->
    <item
        android:left="180dp"
        android:bottom="58.5dp">
        <shape android:shape="line">
            <stroke
                android:color="#999999"
                android:width="1dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <!-- Left-Diagonal Line -->
    <item
        android:right="26dp">
        <rotate android:fromDegrees="67">
            <shape android:shape="line">
                <stroke
                    android:color="#999999"
                    android:width="1dp" />
            </shape>
        </rotate>
    </item>

    <!-- Right-Diagonal Line -->
    <item
        android:left="26dp">
        <rotate android:fromDegrees="293">
            <shape android:shape="line">
                <stroke
                    android:color="#999999"
                    android:width="1dp" />
            </shape>
        </rotate>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

**USE:**

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/custom_shape"/>
```

**OUTPUT:**

[image]

Hope this will help~

Comment: great work but I need both of them separately can you please help me doing it?

Comment: Ok i will do it as soon as possible.