# How can I create button shape

Tags: java, android, xml

I need to create two buttons on an image that completely covers the image, as in the example. How can I create this? Is there a chance to create it with XML?

[image]

Comment: Why don't you use vectors?

Comment: You can do it using Layer-List. [Question Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43474854/custom-shape-using-layerlist-in-xml-android)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can create this using XML in Android. Here’s an example of how you can do it:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/your_image" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button 1"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button 2"
        android:layout_below="@id/button1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

In this example, `RelativeLayout` is used as the parent layout. Inside this layout, an ImageView is defined that covers the entire area of the layout. Then, two Button views are defined.

> The first button (button1) is centered in the parent layout, and the second button (button2) is positioned below the first button.

Please replace `"@drawable/your_image"` with your actual image resource.

Remember to define the buttons’ actions in your Java or Kotlin code!